# Facebook graph, skip share dialog

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api

```
 public void sharePhoto(Bitmap bm){


    SharePhoto sharePhoto = new SharePhoto.Builder()
    .setBitmap(bm)
    .build();

    SharePhotoContent sharePhotoContent = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
            .addPhoto(sharePhoto)
            .build();

    ShareDialog dialog = new ShareDialog(this);
    dialog.show(sharePhotoContent);

}
```

This is my code for sharing a photo on facebook, using facebook graph for Android studio.
The question is:Is there any possible way to skip the share dialog(photo). I want something like "autoclick" the post button (red circled one) with out showing this to my screen.

[image]

Comment: No, there is not. They removed the ways of posting to user profiles via API, and provide only these dialogs now, because automatic posting was abused too much. This _needs_ active user confirmation, so that you can’t go and become a spammer.

Comment: @CBroe Do you know if i can add text ,on text box of share dialog,with code? I searched on facebook graph doc but i found nothing...

Comment: You can suggest a hashtag or a quote, but AFAIK the user will be able to remove them again before sharing, if they don’t like them. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android#Additional